# Python. Подмена библиотеки из site-packages

Tags: python

Есть десктопная программа на Python, которая использует библиотеку (для определенности - pygments, хотя это не так важно). Чтобы пользователю не нужно было заботиться о зависимостях, библиотека pygments поставляется вместе с программой и вполне успешно используется.

Но дело в том, что в самом pygments есть много кода вида

```
from pygments.bla_bla_bla import ...
```

Возникают проблемы, если у пользователя в системе уже установлен pygments, тогда при импорте Python ищет модуль pygments сначала в site-packages и успешно находит. Но нужно сделать, чтобы независимо от того, установлен ли pygments в системе глобально, использовалась именно та версия, что прилагается к программе.

Можно ли это сделать, не трогая код библиотеки pygments?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Здравствуйте.
Вариант "в лоб"

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0,'catalog_with_your_pygments')
import pygments
```

Также может помочь virtualenv, или смена архитектуры Вашего приложения.

Comment: Именно так сейчас и сделано, но, к сожалению, Python ищет модули сначала в site-packages, а потом уже в папках переменной окружения PATH.

Comment: Значит интерпритатор не может его найти в "catalog_with_your_pygments". Возможно не верно указан каталог.

Comment: Нет, находит. Если в системе глобально не установлен pygments, то он импортируется и работает из папки "catalog_with_your_pygments", а если он установлен в системе, то из site-packages.

Comment: Python ищет библиотеки по всем каталогам, указанным в sys.path, по порядку. Вероятно что-то меняет этот порядок.
Могу только посоветовать понаблюдать за переменной sys.path из разных мест в приложении, чтобы понять, в каком месте он изменяется и почему.

Comment: А вообще было бы неплохо посмотреть на вашу переменную sys.path перед импортом pygments.

Comment: Хм, спасибо, надо будет действительно посмотреть, что с ней происходит.

Comment: Да, похоже, это у меня в коде косяк. Иногда pygments импортируется до добавления пути в sys.path.

Answer (score 5):

Ошибка оказалась у меня в коде. Выше @main правильно ответил, что нужно выполнить функцию

```
sys.path.insert(0,'catalog_with_your_pygments')
```

Но поскольку ошибка, на мой взгляд, интересная, то опишу ее подробнее.

Импорт pygments происходил из плагина, в который входит эта библиотека. Плагин состоит из нескольких модулей *.py. Поскольку главная программа не знает заранее, в каком модуле находится главный класс плагина, она последовательно пытается импортировать их все, пока не найдет нужный (главный модуль плагина). Если импорт не удается, то ничего страшного не происходит, программа просто переходит к следующему модулю.

Вызов sys.path.insert(0,'catalog_with_your_pygments') происходит после удачного обнаружения главного модуля плагина.

Если у нас в системе не установлен pygments, то импорт вспомогательного модуля (в процессе поиска главного модуля плагина), который пытается импортировать pygments, просто проваливается, и основная программа переходит к следующему модулю. Затем будет найден главный модуль плагина, он опять попытается импортировать вспомогательный модуль, тот опять попытается импортировать pygments, уже удачно (т.к. к этому времени будет вызван sys.path.insert(0,'catalog_with_your_pygments')).

Если же в системе установлен pygments глобально, то происходит почти то же самое, только вспомогательный модуль удачно импортирует pygments из site-packages, но поскольку главная программа все-равно понимает, что это не главный модуль плагина, то она продолжает искать главный модуль плагина дальше. И когда главный модуль найден, он опять импортирует вспомогательный, а тот уже импортировал pygments, поэтому второй раз его не импортирует, хотя к этому времени был изменен sys.path, и используется pygments, установленный в системе.

Проблема решилась переносом импорта pygments внутрь методов, где он непосредственно нужен.